# Non-abelian Order of $6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I know that it's duplicate, but , How can I prove it?

I know that must be element "$a$" of order 2, and element "$b$" of order 3.
What is the next step? In fact, from what I search it is claimed that if $ba=ab^2$, then the group is $S_3$. Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: it's not clear there..

Comment: Every non-Abelian group of order $6$ has a non-normal subgroup of
order 2, and conclude that every such group is isomorphic to $S_3$

Comment: Just see what the givens tell you: If the group $G$ has order $6$, then there exist elements of orders $2$ and $3$, call them $a$ and $b$ respectively. Then write out the powers/products of $a$ and $b$ and see what you get.

Comment: @Behrouz Maleki , Can you explain more please?

Comment: Not only are you asking a question which can probably be found in most introductory textbooks, you have not put in any effort at all to write it properly. -1

Comment: I retracted the closed vote as the answer there used semi-direct product (which is unfortunate).

Answer (score 3):

You have six elements: $e, a, b, b^2, ab, ab^2$. Prove that they are all different.

Then consider what $ba$ is.

$ba$ can only be $ab$ or $ab^2$ because it cannot be any of the others. (Prove it!)

If $ba=ab$, then the group is abelian.

If $ba=ab^2$, then $a \mapsto (12), b \mapsto (123)$ induces an isomorphism with $S_3$.

Comment: Can you explain what ba can only be ab or ab^2?

Comment: i need check all the cases?

Comment: @MathQues, yes, 4 cases.

Comment: @MathQues About your first comment - do you know that [cancellation laws](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cancellation_Laws) hold in groups?

Answer (score 0):

As $G$ is not Abelian $Z(G)=\{e\}$ and hence $C_G(x) = \langle x\rangle$ for all $e\ne x\in G$. So the class equation reads $6=|G|=1+2n+3m$ where $n$ and $m$ are the numbers of order $3$ and $2$ elements respectively. It follows that $n=m=1$. Pick $x,y\in G$ with $|x|=3$ and $|y|=2$. Assuming that $H=\langle y\rangle$  be a normal subgroup of $ G$. we have $y^x=y$ for all $x\in G$ ,i.e $G$ is Abelian in contradiction to the assumption. So $H$ is not normal and hence $H\cap H^x=\{e\}$ for some $x \in G$ . Then $G\to S_{G/H}\simeq S_3$

Comment: Just because $G$ is not Abelian does not imply that the center of $G$ is $\{ e \}$. There are non-Abelian groups which have non-trivial centers. To fix this, we argue simply: The center of a group is a subgroup. By Lagrange's Theorem and non-Abelianicity, this group is order 1, 2, or 3. If it's order 1, use your argument. If it's order 2 or 3, the order implies this subgroup is cyclic. Then our group has two generators. There can only be two generators as $6 = 2 \cdot 3$. Call them $a$ and $b$, and let $a$ generate the center. Then $a$ commutes with everything....

Comment: But $b$ commutes with powers of itself and $a$, so $G$ is Abelian. Contradiction.